# How to get Grand Total of a column using Webdatarocks and use it in charts

Tags: javascript, webdatarocks

I am using Webdatarocks Pivot table. I get GrandTotal at the bottom of Grid, I want use this Grand Total in the Charts. I checked community but I am unable to find appropriate function which can provide me value of my GrandTotal.

I checked functions in Documentation like getAllMeasures(), getReport() etc. but none of them returns GrandTotal.

There is one way where I can calculate GrandTotal using Javascript function, but in my case GrandTotal will change soon I apply filters in Pivot table.
Please advice how to get them in order to use them intermediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>There isn't a specific API call you could use to retrieve the grand total.</s>

You could though use the [update](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/update/) event handler to trigger your own grand total calculation every time a new filter is applied.

**EDIT:**
On second thought, you could actually use the `getData()` method for this – among everything else, it returns the grand total value. More on this [here](https://www.webdatarocks.com/doc/getdata/).